# How to set up rewrite rule for a list of keywords in the URL?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

### What I wish to do

I have a number of URLs I need to redirect, along with a 301 permanent redirect header being sent to browser. I've determined doing this at the htaccess level is most efficient (as opposed to doing it with a function in the Wordpress site this relates to).

#### The URLs to redirect are:

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=victoria`

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=new-south-wales`

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=queensland`

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=south-australia`

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=tasmania`

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=northern-territory`

#### Where to redirect to

I want to redirect them to the home page: `https://mydomain.com.au/` (I might later choose to redirect them all elsewhere, but I can do that part).

**NOTE**: The query string should be dropped from the redirect.

I am not sure whether it's best to test for all six of those `location=` variables, or to simply test for the one `location=` variable that is not to redirect.

The one `location=` variable that is not to redirect is `?location=western-australia`. E.g.,

`https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=western-australia`

#### Additional considerations

Note that there are other `.../search-result/` URLs that have different variables in the query strings, such as `?weather=...` or `?water=...`. For example, `https://www.mydomain.com.au/search-result/?location=victoria&weather=part-shade&water=&pasture=`

As seen in that example, it's also possible multiple variables will be in the query string, such as `?location=tasmania&weather=&water=moderate&pasture=`.

So I need to test for the presence of the above listed `location=` irrespective of whether or not it has other variables after it. The `location=` variable is always the first in the overall query string.

I am thinking it may be as simple as testing for the presence of `/search-result/` AND that followed by `victoria | tasmania | northern-territory | etc.` in the URL. I can't be 100% sure those words (`victoria`, etc.) won't show up in any other URLs, hence my reason for only redirecting if those words follow either `location=` or `/search-result/`. I suspect `location=` would be a suitable condition.

I've played around with modifying many rewrite rule examples I've found online, and couldn't get anything to work. I'd either get a 501 error (site crash), or nothing would happen at all.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure why someone has voted this as "off topic". In deciding where to post it, a search on Google revealed 159,000 results for `stackoverflow htaccess rewriterule` (see here: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+htaccess+rewriterule+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbtdS7xtXoAhWk4zgGHQYmDrcQrQIoBDAAegQIAhAN&biw=1518&bih=1002 ). If this is not the place to post such a question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you've tried these, but they worked well for me:

- To allow any `location` values, except `western-australia`:

  ```
  # The request path is /search-result/ or maybe /search-result
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search-result/?$

  # ..and the query string 'location' is not empty
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=.+($|&)

  # ..and the value is not 'western-australia'.
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)location=western-australia($|&)

  # Redirect to the home page.
  RewriteRule . / [R=301,NC,L]
  ```
- To allow only certain `location` values:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search-result/?$

  // Allow only certain location values - (<value>|<value>|...).
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)location=(victoria|new-south-wales)($|&)

  RewriteRule . / [R=301,NC,L]
  ```

And note that, in WordPress, you need to put the above *before* the WordPress rules:

```
# This is a sample .htaccess file used on a WordPress site.

# PLACE YOUR CUSTOM RULES HERE.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # ...
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I.e. Place your rules above the `# BEGIN WordPress` line, to avoid getting `404` errors.

And btw, I'm no `htaccess` expert, but hopefully this answer helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried the 2nd example you gave ("To allow only certain location values:"), and it had an odd effect. Using `tasmania` as an example, if the location is in the list, it ends up redirecting to : `https://www.mydomain.com.au/location/tasmania`. If it's not in the list, nothing happens (as expected). Is it possible that after the htaccess redirection, Wordpress is somehow doing a second redirection?

Comment: An analysis on here (http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php)  indicates the first redirect is redirecting to `mydomain.com.au/?location=tasmania`. So it is keeping the query string. How do I eliminate the query string entirely?

Comment: I was above to resolve the above-mentioned issue by changing the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule .* /? [R=301,NC,L]`, which is a suggestion I found here: https://electrictoolbox.com/rewrite-rule-redirect-without-query-string/

Comment: Another solution I found was to add Query String Discard [QSD] flag. E.g., `RewriteRule . / [R=301,NC,L,QSD]`, detailed here, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd . — as that's cleaner, that's what I'll run with. Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: I guess your server's default `RewriteRule` flag is `QSA`? Because in my case, existing query strings didn't get added to the redirect URL.

Comment: As with the automatic redirection to `/location/tasmania`, it could happen if you have a post type or taxonomy with the query var (or slug) `location`, which WordPress would read from the URL and if it presents (e.g. `?location=tasmania`), then WordPress would auto-guess the correct *permalink* (i.e. "pretty URL") for the post/taxonomy having the slug `tasmania`. And all that is called **canonical redirect**, a built-in feature in WordPress. :)